# Solution to second-order non-homogeneous ODE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve the following ODE in steps, as opposed to using Mathematica's solver directly:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \sigma \frac{\partial^2 V (x_t)}{\partial x_t^2} + \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) \frac{\partial V (x_t)}{\partial x_t} - e_+ V (x_t) &= -\frac{- 2x_t + 2 \lambda e_- (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+}
\end{align}

```
ode = 1/2*sigma*V''[x] + ((delta*a0)/a1 - a1*x)*V'[x] - ep*V[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)* lambda)/(em - ep));
```

First, I find the general solution of the homogeneous equation:

```
SolGeneralHomo = DSolveValue[ode[[1]] == 0, V[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

\begin{align}
V^g(x_t) = c^1 H_{-\frac{e_+}{a_1}}\left(\frac{a_1^2 x_t-a_0 \delta }{a_1^{3/2} \sqrt{\sigma} }\right) + c^2 \, _1F_1\left(\frac{e_+}{2 a_1};\frac{1}{2};\frac{\left(a_1^2 x_t -a_0 \delta \right)^2}{a_1^3 \sigma}\right)
\end{align}

Then I find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation. Let's postulate that:
\begin{align}
V (x_t) = h_0 + h_1 x_t 
\end{align}
Substituting the ansatz into the differential equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \sigma \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_t^2} \left( h_0 + h_1 x_t \right) + \left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_t} \left( h_0 + h_1 x_t \right) - e_+ \left( h_0 + h_1 x_t \right) &= -\frac{- 2x_t + 2 \lambda e_+ (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+} \nonumber \\
\left( \frac{\delta a_0}{a_1} - a_1 x_t \right) h_1 - e_+ \left( h_0 + h_1 x_t \right) &= -\frac{- 2x_t + 2 \lambda e_+ (a_0 + a_1 x_t)}{e_- - e_+}
\end{align}

```
h1 = (-2 + 2*lambda*ep*a1)/((em - ep)*(a1 + ep));
h0 = (delta*a0)/(a1*ep)*h1 + (2*lambda*a0)/(em - ep);
SolParticularNonHomo = h0 + h1*x
```

Can you help me understand why Mathematica says that the differential equation is not satisfied?

```
FinalSol = SolGeneralHomo + SolParticularNonHomo // FullSimplify;
Sol = V -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[FinalSol]];
ode /. Sol // FullSimplify
```

The output is:

> (a0 + a1 x) [Lambda] == 0

where even substituting for `a0` and `a1` the equality is not satisfied.

Comment: You can't use undetermined coefficients method (which what you seem to have done with your Ansatz) to solve an ode with variable coefficients. You need to use Variation of parameters. sometimes by luck  undetermined coefficients might work on such ode's, but most of the time it will fail. I used Variation of parameters on this and got the same solution as shown by Mathematica's general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you substitude your Ansatz into the ode, you get

```
ode /. V -> (h0 + h1 # &) /. Equal -> Subtract
eqn = CoefficientList[%, x]
solh = Solve[eqn == 0, {h0, h1}][[1]]
Simplify[ode /. V -> (h0 + h1 # &) /. solh]
```

Particular solution

```
h0+h1 x /.solh
(*(2 a0 (-delta + a1^2 em lambda + a1 delta em lambda +a1 em ep lambda))/(a1 (em - ep) ep (a1 + ep)) - (2 (-1 + a1 em lambda) x)/((a1 + ep) (-em + ep))*)
```

solves the ode!

Complete solution `V -> Function[x, SolGeneralHomo[x] + h0 + h1 x /. solh]`

```
SolGeneralHomo = DSolveValue[ode[[1]] == 0, V , x] // FullSimplify;
ode /.  V -> Function[x, SolGeneralHomo[x] + h0 + h1 x /. solh] //Simplify;
Collect[% /. Equal -> Subtract, {C[1], C[2]}, FullSimplify]
(* 0 *)
```

fullfills the ode too.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help and neat answer.

Comment: You're welcome!